# How do remove a systemd-inhibit block?

Tags: systemd, gnome, suspend

The documentation about [Systemd's Inhibitor Locks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) and also [man systemd-inhibit](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-systemd-inhibit/) go to great length to explain how to start a process in a way as it blocks something (e.g. the `handle-lid-switch` event).

I was unable to find a way to allow me to remove such a "lock"/"inhibit"/"block".

**Question:** Is there a way to remove the `systemd-inhibit` lock, for instance via a `dbus` message?

**Background:** what would I need to remove a inhibitor lock for**

My Laptop has a laptop-lid close switch, which `systemd-logind` monitors and in case the lid is closed suspends the laptop -  functionality "`close-lid -> suspend`".

Once the laptop is placed in its docking station, to make user of a bigger screen, Gnome's gsd-power arbitrarily ( and  *erroneously* and without any available setting in Gnome to change it ) decides to create a inhibitor lock, preventing the functionality "`close-lid -> suspend`" to work.

Knowing how to remove an inhibitor lock, would allow me to remedy the erronous setting done by Gnome's gnome-setting-deamon power `gsd-power`. Gnome's setting is wrong, because manually invoking suspend `systemctl suspend` showed indeed no problem.

The inhibitor lock I would like to remove, as listed in `systemd-inhibit --list` is this:

```
     Who: alex (UID 1000/alex, PID 4248/gsd-power)
    What: handle-lid-switch
     Why: Multiple displays attached
    Mode: block
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the developer documentation of the inhibitor locks:](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/)

> Inhibit() returns a single value, a file descriptor that encapsulates
>   the lock. As soon as the file descriptor is closed (and all its
>   duplicates) the lock is automatically released. If the client dies
>   while the lock is taken the kernel automatically closes the file
>   descriptor so that the lock is automatically released. A delay lock
>   taken this way should be released ASAP on reception of
>   PrepareForShutdown(true) (see below), but of course only after
>   execution of the actions the application wanted to delay the operation
>   for in the first place.

You probably don't want to kill `gsd-power`, so you would need to close the file descriptor that encapsulates the lock. It is most likely held by `gsd-power`. Forcing another process to close one of its file descriptors is not a normal thing to do, and might cause some side effects within `gsd-power`. But if you want to do it, [read this question in Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323146/9197000)

Instead, you might try removing `gsd-power`'s permission to execute the DBus action `org.freedesktop.login1.inhibit-handle-lid-switch`. The [man page `dbus-daemon(1)`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html) might be helpful.

Comment: thank you for your answer and its quoted information. It is nice that some suggestions regarding the problem at hand `gsd-power`were included. However to comment upon then simply (1) you are mistaken if possible I "probably *do* want to kill `gsd-power`", as the culprit for this. (2) the suggestion to close another processes fd seems intriguing, but futile, I checked the source and `gsd-power` will continously interfere, not just only once. (3) Do you think  `dbus` even capable of limiting access to `logind`'s `Inhibit` method from `gsd-power`, I peaked into `dbus`docu and it seems impossibe:(